# Extension Host Terminated unexpectedly vscode mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

Alright, I need some assistance from an expert.

I'm still relatively new to programming so I'm not 100% with it. I'm on my mac and have ran into the issue on my VSCode where I get an error in the bottom right  saying "Extension Host Terminated unexpectedly"

Can someone please assist me with this? I have followed along with other recommended processes to fix this issue such as uninstall extensions and had no luck.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a large amount of research and trying different things the best fix for me was to uninstall VS Code and reinstall the earlier version 1.42